# Two queries union issue

Tags: mysql

I am currently working on a small PHP script on which I need to  perform a union query.
I want to take 7 elements from a query and 1 element from another query both are performed on the same table .
The first one is this :

```
SELECT * FROM (
                select * from quiz 
                where id != '10' 
                  and langage = 'ar' 
                order by nshares 
                DESC LIMIT 15) a 
order by rand() limit 7
```

The second one is:

```
select * from quiz  
where id != '10' 
  and langage = 'ar' 
order by qid DESC 
limit 1
```

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM (
                select * from quiz 
                where id != '10' 
                  and langage = '$loga' 
                order by nshares DESC 
                LIMIT 15) a 
order by rand() 
limit 7 
union 
select * from quiz  
where id != '10' 
  and langage = '$loga' 
order by qid DESC 
limit 1
```

But it doesn't seems to work.Can anyone help  please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.  You just need parentheses around the subqueries:

```
(select q.*
 from (select q.*
       from quiz q
       where id <> '10' and langage = '$loga'
       order by nshares DESC
       limit 15
      ) q
 order by rand()
 limit 7
) union
(select q.*
 from quiz q
 where id <> '10' and langage = '$loga'
 order by qid desc
 limit 1
);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33cb86/1) is a SQL Fiddle showing that the syntax works.

Notes:

- `union` incurs overhead to remove duplicates.  You should use `union all` if you don't want this overhead.
- Your query could return 7 or 8 rows (assuming there is enough matching data), because the random row in the second query could match the first query.
- Your syntax error is because `order by` is only allowed at the end of a `union`/`union all` query (unless you use subqueries).
- If `id` is a number, don't use single quotes for the comparison.  It confuses people and can confuse the optimizer.

Comment: An expression was expected. (near "(" at position 19)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 19)
This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "select" at position 20)
This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "order by" at position 158)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "order by" at position 158)

Comment: @TestilaSupport . . . It *does* work.  I just put in a link to a SQL Fiddle (and I didn't even have to change anything in the query).

Comment: The second query seems always to be the last reasult can you just sort them randomly so the second query is also in a random position with the other 7 results  ?

Comment: Fixed everything :) Thank you so much for your help !